# Sorting Vehicles Registrations

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Using PHP or MySQL, I'm looking for a way to sort vehicle registrations based on their age, then by the characters. In the UK, vehicles are registered in 2 phases. Phase 1 is the year in 2 digit form, phase 2 is the year in 2 digit form PLUS 50. This data is stored in a MySQL database.

EG phase 2 this year will be 66, phase 1 is 16.

This is what I'm looking for:

```
* AB01 BBB
* BA01 BBB
* CC51 CCC
* AA02 AAA
* DD52 DDD
```

This is what I'm currently getting:

```
* AA02 AAA
* AB01 BBB
* BA01 BBB
* CC51 CCC
* DD52 DDD
```

The numberplates are stored in the database as above. Private Registrations are stored in a separate field and therefore are not relevant to this question.

Thanks in advance for your help, and if I can answer any questions please let me know.

Bryn

Comment: and how you think regex is gonna help you in this?

Comment: What is the code you use to get the current results?

Comment: What is your question?  What is the query you are using for your current results?

Comment: You don't need a regex. Sort the results in your SQL query by `(substring+50)%100`

Comment: Could you please what you had tried so far ? As you have mentioned that you are getting wrong out put from the database ? Will you share your mysql query or php code so  that we can help you to get the answer.

Comment: Well you can use regex to sort out the Phase 1 and sort them,
and then sort out Phase 2, sort and concatinate Phase 1&2 at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit stupid, but you can use `SUBSTR()` for that because the logic is flat:

```
SELECT
    plate
FROM
    platesTable
ORDER BY
    SUBSTR(plate, 4, 1),
    SUBSTR(plate, 3, 2),
    SUBSTR(plate, 1, 2)
```

Output is:

```
+----------+
| plate    |
+----------+
| AB01 BBB |
| BA01 BBB |
| CC51 CCC |
| AA02 AAA |
| DD52 DDD |
+----------+
5 rows in set
```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you so much.